# how to animate icon fa-circle using CSS to look as recording video blinking red dot?

Tags: html, css

I have this red icon in CSS:

```
<div><i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i>&nbsp; LIVE </div>
```

How can I animate it to blink on an interval?

You remember in webcams and recorders cameras you can see a red dot blinking when is actually recording? I want the same effect, how can I do that in CSS? is it hard?

For example:
http://jsbin.com/loxayazega/edit?html,output

Answer (score 49, accepted):

***Try using this CSS:***

*you can change `blinker 1.5s` value to control blinking speed.*

```
.Blink {
    animation: blinker 1.5s cubic-bezier(.5, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;  
}

@keyframes blinker {  
  from { opacity: 1; }
  to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

See [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mdz87jy1/). *I hope it works for you, thanks.*

Comment: I guess this is exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: with 0.4s my client said : Now we're live :p .....Thx alot :D

Comment: Without the font-awesome dependency, you can simply use this UTF-8 circle: `<b class="text-danger Blink">&#11044;</b>`